# simple temperature conversion questions

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConTempConversion_LeeMichelle
 {
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double fTemp;
            double cTemp;
            double convertC;
            double convertF;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
            Console.Write("Enter choice: ");

            Console.ReadKey();

            int ichoice = 0;

            do
            {

                if (ichoice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
                    fTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    convertC = ConvertCelcius(fTemp);
                    Console.WriteLine(fTemp + "Fahrenheit is " + convertC + "Celsius");
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
                         Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
                    Console.ReadKey();


                }
                if (ichoice == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Celsius temperature: ");
                    cTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    convertF = ConvertFahrenheit(cTemp);
                    Console.WriteLine(cTemp + "Celsius is " + convertF + "Fahrenheit");
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
                    Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
                if (ichoice == 3)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the temperature conversion application. Please come again.");



                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please choose again!");

                }

            }
            while (ichoice > 3);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static double ConvertCelcius(double c){
                double f;

                return f= 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;
        }
        static double ConvertFahrenheit(double f) {
             double c;

                 return c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32);

        }
    }
}
```

so suppose the user has three options from 1 - 3. After option 3, there will be an error alert. my problem is why this code gives me an infinity loop? what did I do wrong? can I put break after each if statment?
Please help, thank you!

Comment: Among the *many* problems with the code, you don't seem to be setting `ichoice` anywhere. Where is your user input?

Comment: You didn't assign a value to Ichoice from console.readkey()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each time you call `Console.ReadKey` you should store returning value.You are receiving input from user but you didn't store it anywhere.

First you can create a function to get `ichoice`, and force user to enter the correct value:

```
static void GetChoice(ref int ichoice)
{
     string input = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.Write("Enter choice: ");   
     bool result = int.TryParse(input, out ichoice);

     if (!result)
     {
          while (!result && ichoice > 3)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Invalid value.Try again:");
              input = Console.ReadLine();
              result = int.TryParse(input, out ichoice);
          }
      }
}
```

Then use this function whenever you need to make a choice.

Here is the working version or your program:

```
double fTemp;
double cTemp;
double convertC;
double convertF;

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
int ichoice = 0;
GetChoice(ref ichoice);
do
{
  if (ichoice == 1)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
       fTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       convertC = ConvertCelcius(fTemp);
       Console.WriteLine(fTemp + "Fahrenheit is " + convertC + "Celsius");
       Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
       Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
       GetChoice(ref ichoice);
  }
  if (ichoice == 2)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter Celsius temperature: ");
       cTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine(cTemp + "Celsius is " + cTemp  + "Fahrenheit");
       Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
       Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________");
       GetChoice(ref ichoice);   
  }
  if (ichoice == 3)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the temperature conversion application. Please come again.");
  }
  else
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please choose again!");
  }

}
while (ichoice < 3);

}
static double ConvertCelcius(double c)
{
    double f;
    return f = 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;
}
static double ConvertFahrenheit(double f)
{
    double c;
    return c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32);
}
```

And here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/bkegSAFL

Comment: Not KeyChar, that gives character values (ASCII codes). More like ReadLine() and int.Parse().

Comment: Console.Read seems more appropriate

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it right... thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `do...while` loop without anything to ever exit it. When the loop begins, `ichoice` is already set in stone. So you'll always be stuck in that loop!

Comment: But `ichoice` is initialized to 0 which would terminate the loop after 1 iteration. We seem to be missing something from the OP's code...

Comment: @dvnrrs: No, it would trigger the final `else`, which would display the "Invalid choice" message and loop back to the start of the `do..while` loop again.

Comment: No... while(ichoice>3) fails and the loop exits. There's no "continue" anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning a value to `ichoice` If I were you, I would try something like this:

```
    int ichoice = 0;

    int.TryParse(Console.ReadKey().ToString(), out ichoice );

    do
    {

        if (ichoice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
            fTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            convertC = ConvertCelcius(fTemp);
            Console.WriteLine(fTemp + "Fahrenheit is " + convertC + "Celsius");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
                 Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadKey().ToString(), out ichoice );
```

Add the `int.TryParse(Console.ReadKey().ToString(), out ichoice );` everywhere you have `Console.Readline()`. What this is doing is getting the user input and converting it to an integer (if it's not an integer, then the value is 0).

Also add this:

```
            if (ichoice == 3)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the temperature conversion application. Please come again.");
            break;


            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please choose again!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadKey().ToString(), out ichoice );
            }
```

Finally, remove this (I'm not quite sure what it was for...)

```
        while (ichoice > 3);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: David, this is a loop ... say if my choice is 4 then the loop will stop and alert the user that is a wrong input.

Comment: @Michelle, isn't that what you wanted? What do you want to happen when the input is 4?

Comment: when input is greater than 3, there will be an alert message says it is a wrong choice and please try it again.. I have adjusted my code last night and it seem to work just fine.. thank you for helping me anyway, I am appreciated truly.

Comment: @Michelle, you should mark as the answer whichever helped you the most, or you could answer it yourself so that future users will know how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do some prep work before your condition, the most straightforward way involves combining your loop with a separate structure.

This is the format to use when your loop condition is at the beginning of the loop:

```
prep work

while (condition) // if false then loop body will never run
{
   loop body
}
```

This is the format to use when the loop condition is at the end of the loop:

```
prep work

do
{
   loop body
}
while (condition); // loop body will always execute at least once
```

In this case, you have some prep work to do before each iteration--you want to get the key press from the user each time. For this, I recommend the following from *Code Complete*:

```
while (true) // loop termination condition is inside the loop
{
   prep work

   if (condition)
   {
      break;
   }

   loop body
}
```

In your case, it would look something like:

```
Console.Write("Enter choice: ");

while (true) // loop termination condition is inside the loop
{
   Console.ReadKey();

   if (ichoice == 3)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(...);
      break;
   }

   ...
}
```

Also, consider changing most of your `if`s into `else if`s; otherwise, you're repeatedly checking the condition even when you've gone through one case.

Answer (score 0):

you should assign a value to iChoice. and set your while to read a terminating character. like:

```
 namespace YourNameSpace
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
double fTemp;
double cTemp;
double convertC;
double convertF;
int iChoice;


Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
Console.Write("Enter choice(0 to exit): ");

iChoice = Console.Read();

do{
    switch(iChoice)
    {
       case 1:
          Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
          fTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          convertC = ConvertCelcius(fTemp);
          Console.WriteLine(fTemp + "Fahrenheit is " + convertC + "Celsius");
      case 2:
          Console.WriteLine("Enter Celsius temperature: ");
          cTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          convertF = ConvertFahrenheit(cTemp);
          Console.WriteLine(cTemp + "Celsius is " + convertF + "Fahrenheit");


   }
   Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
   Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
   Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
   Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
   Console.Write("Enter choice(0 to exit): ");

   iChoice = Console.Read();


   }while(iChoice != 0);


 }
 static double ConvertCelcius(double c){
            double f;

            return f= 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;
    }
    static double ConvertFahrenheit(double f) {
         double c;

             return c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32);

    }

}
```

Comment: message to the user to select a choice or enter 0 to end.